# Swap the adjacent character only if string has even length else print invalid length

Tags: java

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    static String solve(String str) throws Exception {
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            String str = br.readLine();
            try {
                System.out.println(solve(str));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first line of input contains a single integer representing the number of string to be inputted such as 2 so string will be:

```
hgtsgf
tadad
```

If the string has even characters without any numeric value then swap the adjacent and if string contains odd characters then print invalid string as output.

Comment: Can you fix the code in your post? You copied it wrong, you have the main method *inside* the solve method

Comment: Also, while you're at it, can you add what your actual question is?

Comment: I am trying to swap if user input even string without numeric characters in it and for odd inputted string print invalid.

Comment: Can you tell _how_ exactly you need to swap the adjacent characters?  There are at least two cases: a first character bubbles up to the end of string `"abcd" -> `1) `"bacd"` -> 2) `"bcad"` -> 3) `"bcda"` or the characters are swapped inside the pairs: `"abcd" -> `1) `"bacd"` -> 2) `"badc"`.  Also, what should be returned for _empty_ string?  Its length is 0 which is even, but there's no character to swap.

Comment: What happens if the length is even and it does have numeric characters? We need examples for all cases.

Comment: What happens if the length is even and it does have numeric characters? We need examples for all cases. – NomadMaker for this scenario print invalid input.

Comment: All test Cases: Example :                                                                                             
3 ( first line contains single integer representing number of test cases )                                                                                         kfkfks    --------------> fkfksk                                                                                             sdf          -------------> invalid string                                                                                                               sasfd3sf   -----------> invalid input

Answer (score 0):

I hope you searched something like this

```
public static String solve(String in) {
    String[] chars = in.split("");
    if(chars.length%2==1) {
        return "invalid";
    }
    String ret = "";
    for(int i=0; i<chars.length-1; i+=2) {
        ret += chars[i+1] + chars[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the following statement:

> *If the string has even characters without any numeric value then swap the adjacent and if string contains odd [number of] characters then print invalid string as output*

The solution may be as follows:

```java
public static String solve(String str) {
    String result = "Invalid string";  // prepare result
    if (null != str && str.length() % 2 == 0) { // check the null and length of the input
        
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
            if (Character.isDigit(arr[i]) || Character.isDigit(arr[i + 1])) {
                // if any digit found, return "Invalid string"
                return result;
            }
            // do the swap
            char t = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = t;
        }
        // make the result string
        result = new String(arr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Tests:

```java
String[] tests = {
    "abcd", "AB", "", "AAaaBBbb", // even length
    "1234", // digits
    "AbCdE", "A", // odd length
    null,   
    "A.B+C-D!" // even length without digits
};
for (String t : tests) {
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", t, solve(t));
}
```

Output:

```
abcd -> badc
AB -> BA
 -> 
AAaaBBbb -> AAaaBBbb
1234 -> Invalid string
AbCdE -> Invalid string
A -> Invalid string
null -> Invalid string
A.B+C-D! -> .A+B-C!D
```